# git clone shallow but fetch changes non-shallow?

Tags: git

I am cloning a branch of very large git repo like this:

`git clone -b v3 --depth=1 $REPO`

Now, a few days later, I want to fetch the latest commits since my clone.

Using `git fetch --depth=1` does reduce the whole commit history to one commit, but I specifically need all the commits between the cloning and now.

`git fetch` alone will retrieve all commits - even ones before my clone (which is not wanted, as the commit history is huge).

How can I fetch all commits since my shallow cloning but not commits before that?

Comment: I think this is impossible 'automatically'. You need to count the amount of commits somehow (you could use git log for that) and use that depth.

Comment: @kabanus How would I count the commits of the remote branch without fetching it?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't think about it too much in the comment. This may be a good solution for you (from [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch)):

> shallow-since=
>
> > Deepen or shorten the history of a shallow repository to include all
> >     reachable commits after .

This way you just need to remember the date of your original commit.